# How to separate paths in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Hello I am having problem separating paths and coloring each path with different color in Photoshop. Is it even possible to do that I picked Pen TOOL - path...

[image]
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate the vector layer (or path in the path's panel) and delete everything but one shape. Repeat for each desired separate shape. Make certain the end points are connected after deleting pieces.

Comment: I am at Paths but I don't really understand, sorry. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "magic wand tool" in selecting what part you want to edit.

Comment: Thanks I tried to use that, but it's not working.